# Should my orport be public facing?

Tags: configuration, security, relays, linux

I port scanned my VPS (tor relay) and noticed both port 9001 and 9030 are public facing; accessible to the entire internet. Is this normal? How might a malicious actor interact with these ports? Could someone use tor-arm to connect?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is normal and infact required, if you want to be a relay.

They could interact with them like any Tor client or relay.

No, neither of those are control ports.